# Тень в css

Tags: css3

Добавил тень на сайт с помощью css, вот так:
box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 3px;
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы тень не отображалась сверху и снизу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
box-shadow: 3px 0 3px -3px #666, -3px 0 3px -3px #666; 
 -moz-box-shadow: 3px 0 3px -3px #666, -3px 0 3px -3px #666; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 0 3px -3px #666, -3px 0 3px -3px #666;
```

*[подсказка](http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=тень+слева+и+справа+css&oq=тень+слева)*

Answer (score 1):

У Вас первые два значения - по нулям. А это и есть положение тени по осям. Изменяйте их, и тень будет двигаться. Так что просто сдвиньте так, что бы она отображалась только там, где нужно